My vercel deployment doesn't work, error in the html
I'm trying to host a project on Vercel,
type of monolithic architecture project, with a backend API in Express and pages in React that integrate this API's routes for data, but Vercel does not build the javascript in the HTML page, it executes the API function and leaves its wheel open, but in the /root html Bundle.js is not sent to the client, so nothing appears
My vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    { "src": "src/api/index.ts", "use": "@vercel/node" },
    {
      "src": "package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": { "distDir": "dist" }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/api/(.*)", "dest": "src/api/index.ts" },
    { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/index.html" }
  ]
}

My Package.json scripts
{
  "name": "efood",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.tsx",
  "scripts": {
    "vercel-build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "test": "jest",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist/*",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "update-deps": "ncu -u && npm install",
    "dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    "dev-server": "webpack serve --mode=production",
    "dev-api-server": "nodemon --watch src --exec tsx src/api/index.ts"
  },

Yes, I used webpack in the project, but the dist build occurs correctly, even dev-server and dev-api-server run normally on my machine
Please help me
I need the bundle.js to be sent to the client, for react to build the page
